# R Markdown plots inline, but keep console output to the console

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Is there a way to get plots to show inline when I execute R Markdown chunks, and at the same time exclude console output from being shown inline?

In other words I want `plot(cars)` to show inline below, but I do not want `cars` to show inline. I'd prefer to have `cars` go to the console. I often run analysis while I'm creating a notebook and it's nice to have plots as reference. But I don't want a whole bunch of console output clogging up my notebook.

If I <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> while highlighting `cars` it spits the output below the R Markdown chunk. Maybe there's a shortcut where it'd spit it out to my console.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
plot(cars)
cars
```
````

and in case you're wondering this is what I call "console output" for say `cars`... see below...

```
speed dist
<dbl> <dbl>
4   2           
4   10          
7   4           
7   22          
8   16          
9   10          
10  18          
10  26          
10  34          
11  17
```

Comment: For me it goes to the console too... it's just minimised by default

Comment: Try this link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889728/rstudio-running-in-console-in-rmd-chunk